# Can't set Cookies in browser even though header is present

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cookies

I was working on adding cookies to my project, full source [here](https://github.com/Mr-Antivirus/Riur), but I ran into an issue where I can't set the cookies properly. I made a new api route that just creates a cookie and sends an object to the client.

**server/routes/todo.routes.js**

```
router.get('/todos', (req, res) => {
    res.cookie('mycookie', 'a_value')
    return res.send([{id:'1',isCompleted:false,text:'something'}])
})
```

If I call this api route directly, the browser renders the object and the cookie is set. The problem is when I call this api via AJAX from a rendered page, I still get the same response, but cookies aren't set. **NOTE:** I export the router and do app.use('/api', exported_object_here), so the URL is /api/todos.

**shared/actions/todo.actions.js**

```
export const getTodos = () => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        return fetch('/api/todos')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(todo => dispatch(_receiveTodos(todo)))
            .catch(err => dispatch(_errorHandler(err)));
    }
};
```

I have no idea why the browser would act differently in that situation, especially with something so simple. Do you all have any clue what could cause this?

Comment: Ajax calls do set cookies so I think you need to show us the code where you're reading the cookie and concluding it isn't there.   In your `res.cookie()` call, you are not setting an expiration so that creates a session cookie.

Comment: You can also use the network tab in the Chrome debugger to examine the request/response and actual cookies in the browser to see if the cookie was returned from the API request and to see exactly what is stored in the browser afterwards and then if you make a subsequent request to see what cookie is sent with the next request.  This will likely show you where things are going different than expected.

Comment: I checked that, that is how I observed that it worked in one situation and not the other. Regardless of how I call that URL, I always get the cookie header sent to the client. If I go to the API URL directly, I get the header and the client saves it in the resources. Then it sends the cookie on subsequent requests. If I use the Ajax on the page, I also get the same cookie, but the browser doesn't store it and it doesn't get sent on the requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `withCredentials` on your XHR request (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/withCredentials)

Comment: This doesn't look like a cross origin ajax request.

Comment: Actually, this was the issue. I needed to set `credentials: 'same-origin'` as options to my fetch call. Once I did that, it worked!

Comment: @Mr_Antivius - So, why does your code show `fetch('/api/todos')` if this is actually a cross origin request?

Comment: @jfriend00 - I see what you're getting at, but I just know that I followed [this](https://github.com/github/fetch#sending-cookies) and it worked. I'm not sure what else could be the issue.

Comment: @jfriend00 - So I just tried the same code, but instead with jQuery (I was using [isomorphic-fetch](https://github.com/matthew-andrews/isomorphic-fetch)) and it worked without having to set withCredentials or anything. So I assume it's a problem with the npm package.

Comment: @Mr_Antivius - Well, the MDN doc and actual fetch spec are not entirely clear on this topic.  It is clear that the polyfill you are using requires the credentials option be set to get cookies.  I can find conflicting places on MDN where it says one thing in one place and something else in another place.  I cannot really tell what [the spec](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/) says (it's not particularly clear), though if I were to guess what it means, I think it requires credentials to use cookies.  In any case, I guess you got a solution.

Comment: @Mr_Antivius - jQuery uses plain XMLHttpRequest which does not require credentials in order to process cookies for the same origin so that's why jQuery works.

Comment: Even on same-origin, you need credentials set, because your request is a preflight request due to the `Content-Type` being `application/json` (it doesn't fulfill the requirements for simple requests that do not need credentials). See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Simple_requests